# error in zend session database for php7

Tags: php, database, session, zend-framework, php-7

My application need to use **database** instead of **file** for the **session management**.
My Application is based on Zend Framework 1.12.17, php 5.6.25 and actualy on wampserver

That is my config.ini

```
resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 864000
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
resources.session.gc_probability = 1
resources.session.gc_divisor = 100
resources.session.saveHandler.class = "Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.name = "app_session"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary = "id"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.modifiedColumn = "modified"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.dataColumn = "data"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.lifetimeColumn = "lifetime"
```

When I want to upgrade php to php 7.0.10, a warning occurred

> Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (D:\wamp\www\myapp\top\session) in D:\wamp\www\myapp\top\library\versions\ZendFramework-1.12.17-minimal\library\Zend\Session.php on line 732

I'm looking for the origin of this problem. Do you have an idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On September 2016, [Zend Framework 1 is reached EOL](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2016-06-28-zf1-eol.html) (end-of-life). This means it will not be improved anymore. The codebase is too old to work well with PHP 7.

Anyway, you have at least two option:

1. Downgrade to or run in parallel PHP 5.6 on your server to support ancient ZF1 app.
2. Write your own session save handler by extending the DbTable handler as [suggested here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/665).

Comment: I'll test the second option. If there is problem, I'll downgrade to php5.6. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

The issue is written here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/665#issue-127528467

> Since an update that returns 0 but doesn't throw an exception was still a successful query with no error

Hence the function `write` will return `false` instead of `true`, and PHP 7.0 requires a `true` result.

You can fix this by changing, in `Zend/Session/SaveHandler/DbTable.php`:

```
if ($this->update($data, $this->_getPrimary($id, self::PRIMARY_TYPE_WHERECLAUSE))) {
```

To:

```
if (is_int($this->update($data, $this->_getPrimary($id, self::PRIMARY_TYPE_WHERECLAUSE)))) {
```

Or you can also remove the `if`, turn it into an instruction, and keep the `$return = true;`. Because on error, the query should raise an Exception, so any `update()` without Exception is good.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to edigus answer here is such a simple implementation of the extended save handler:

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/Session/SaveHandler/DbTable.php';

// NOTE: To fix an issue with Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable on PHP 7 this class extends it and overrides the write
// method to simply always return true.
//
// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985594/1510754
// See: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/665
// See: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/pull/654

class My_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable extends Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable
{

    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        parent::write($id, $data);
        return true;
    }

}
```