# session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user) on Zend

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

Can anyone please elaborate this error. The code works fine without any issue in **php 5.6** but with **php 7** looks like it does generate an error. Can anyone tell me the reason please. I am using Zend Framework 1.

```
<b>Warning</b>:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data 
(user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is 
correct (/var/lib/php/sessions) in <b>/_DIRPATH_/library/Zend/Session.php</b> on line <b>732</b><br />
```

This shows in the console. What can I do to fix this error? I think this caused because ZF1 has reached its EOL and it doesn't support php 7 a lot. Is there a walk around for this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error in zend session database for php7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491295/error-in-zend-session-database-for-php7)

Comment: How can I walk around that issue in ZF1 ? @spinsch

Comment: this is a solution for your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985594/1721486